# Create a custom dataSourceClassName

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework, hikaricp

I have an application using playFramework, Spring & Hibernate like this:

[Play-Spring-Data-JPA-APP](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-spring-data-jpa)

I want to implement multiple datasources with AbstractRoutingDataSource, so I have my custom class:

```
package mx;

import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource;

/**
 *
 */
public class MyRouting extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        System.out.println("Logic to determine the datasource");
        return "key";
    }
}
```

But when I try to set the datasource in my application.conf like this:
`db.routingDS.dataSourceClassName = mx.MyRouting`

I get a

```
[error] play - Error while stopping the application
play.api.PlayException: Cannot load plugin[An exception occurred during Plugin [com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HikariCPPlugin] initialization]
at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:154) ~[play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
at play.api.WithDefaultPlugins$$anonfun$plugins$1$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(Application.scala:130) ~[play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:0.13.5]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:0.13.5]
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318) ~[scala-library.jar:0.13.5]
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.MyRouting]
at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:94) ~[play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743) ~[play_2.10-2.3.10.jar:2.3.10]
at com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HikariCPDBApi$$anonfun$2.apply(HikariCPDBApi.scala:64) ~[play-hikaricp_2.10-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
at com.edulify.play.hikaricp.HikariCPDBApi$$anonfun$2.apply(HikariCPDBApi.scala:44) ~[play-hikaricp_2.10-2.0.6.jar:2.0.6]
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:0.13.5]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.MyRouting
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:120) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolUtilities.initializeDataSource(PoolUtilities.java:102) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:156) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.8.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mx.MyRouting
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
```

(Im also using a db configuration with HikariCP)

I also tried to generate a jar with the class and the result is the same, Anyone has some idea about it? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are trying to achieve is not possible thru play application config directly. The main problem is that by default play expects an URL and driver to create the Datasource (at least in play 2.3 and play 2.4).

In other words, play expects that always that you are going to create a datasource, you will be using a connection pool to a real database not to a RoutingDatasource.

Since you are using a JPA seed, you need to access the resources thru JNDI, so you need to add the datasource to the JNDI in some way.

This is how it can be achived:

In the application.conf only declare the datasources that will interact to the database. As many as you want:

```
# Database configuration
#
db.mydb1.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.mydb1.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.mydb1.jndiName=DB1DS
db.mydb2.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.mydb2.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
db.mydb2.jndiName=DB2DS
```

Now, in the persistence.xml ensure that you do not declare any datasource. (neither jta or not jta)

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, in the Global.java or Global.scala, force into the JNDI the RoutingDatasource. The nasty part is that there's no documentation or post anyware of how Play manage the JNDI. Basically, Play creates an on memory JNDI using the class "InitialContext". This context is writable (thanks god) cause there are many application servers that protect their initial context.

```
//This is the routing Datasource in spring context
@Bean
public RoutingDatasource routingDataSource() {
  RoutingDatasource rd = new RoutingDatasource();
  java.util.HashMap ds = new java.util.HashMap();
  ds.put("DB1DS","DB1DS");
  ds.put("DB2DS","DB2DS");
  rd.setTargetDataSources(ds);
  return rd;
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
  java.util.Map props = new java.util.HashMap();  
  try{
//This is the magic line.
  ((javax.naming.Context)(new javax.naming.InitialContext())).bind("routingDataSource", ctx.getBean("routingDataSource"));
   }catch(Exception e){}
  props.put("javax.persistence.jtaDataSource", "routingDataSource");
            return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(DEFAULT_PERSISTENCE_UNIT,props);
}
```

And finally just as you mentioned, create your own RoutingDatasource:

```
public class RoutingDatasource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

   @Override
   protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
     return selectRandom("DB1DS","DBDS2");
   }
}
```

Thats all. I hope it helps solving your problem.